# To link to Hostinger server using VPS I get this error (ssh server connect to host xxx port 22: Connection timed out)

Tags: node.js, hosting

I have been trying to connect to VPS server of Hostinger using Mac, but I keep getting this error above.

After I open my terminal, I write
**ssh root@xxxxxxxxxxxx**,     note: xxxxxxxxx is my VPS IP address.
Then my terminal gives me this:
**ssh: connect to host xxxxxxx port 22: Operation timed out**

Please help me to get into my server.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure the SSH server is running. This can most likely be done by running `systemctl status sshd`.
2. check your firewall configuration - it might block SSH traffic per default